# Replacing specified characters using Regex .net

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I have a small Regex here where I am removing all the white spaces from within a file and replacing them with '-'.

I want to also replace other characters with '-' such as ',' and '_'.

How can I list these characters in my regex?

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\s+");

string fileName = r.Replace(Files.Name, @"-");
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"[\s,_-]+");

string fileName = r.Replace(Files.Name, @"-");
```

Be aware that the `-` must be the first, the last or you'll need escaping.

Comment: @FailedDev It was a pedantic with a `:-)` or a `:-D`... A pe `:-D` antic

Comment: Just saying :) no offense intended! :)

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(\s|-|,|_)+");
```

Comment: Uh, but that's an inefficent way to do it. @xanatos' version is cleaner and faster.

Comment: I think it's more readable as you don't need to worry about ordering or escaping characters, but that's personal preference. I think we're way into micro-optimization to call this 'inefficient' though. Yes, it may be a few milli-seconds slower if you loop over it thousands of times. Does that matter ? If absolute fastest is needed, straight string replace for each of the various characters would be faster still. Readability would generally be more important IMO.